# Proximity matching with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, similarity

I am working on an application where I have to "match" a lot of strings for the existence of different words and phrases. The normal method I am using right now though has to get a 100% match in order for it to be true:

An example:

```
string1 = "This education takes (around) 2 years."
string2 = "It will take around 2 years to finish this education."
```

Of course I could write a standard regexp for it to match both of them, but normally I don't know the content of the strings I am getting in.

Is there a way to match proximity in that case? So I could write a match condition and e.g. define that the proximity has to be at least 80% in order for it to be true?

P.S. I am running Ruby 2.0.0-p353 and Rails 4.0.1

Comment: this is about semantic distance, broad subject

Comment: Any idea about how I could handle it? Maybe there's a Rubygem for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the [amatch](https://github.com/flori/amatch) gem can help you. It implements a lot of different algorithms you can compare and play with.

Alternatively, check out [fuzzy-string-match](https://github.com/kiyoka/fuzzy-string-match), which implements only one algorithm and is maybe easier to start with :)

Comment: I'll have a look. Thanks!